# blank spaces on catalog pages

Tags: product-list, category-products, category-listing

there are **blank spaces** showing up on pages where products are listed. These random blank blocks instead of just listing the next product show up on the storefront and cannot figure out why. HELP?

> https://store.maniosdigital.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=vocas
>   https://store.maniosdigital.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=hawk

Comment: css problem nothing issue in code

Answer (score 0):

Product Name length is created issue.

add this css on your css:

```
.products-grid .product-name {    min-height: 61px;}
```

and it will resolved your issue

Comment: apologize for the stupid question as i am not hugely familiar with css or an type of coding no matter how elementary, where do i find the css language to add this? And where within the language can i add it?